# Recommender system: Give a feature more significance than another

Tags: bigdata, recommender-system, pyspark

I am trying to build a recommender system that predicts hotel prices based on a great number of features. I have a column representing the hotel rating out of 5 and another column indicating the number of reviews for said hotel. In my data set, some hotels have a rating of 5 for example, but with only one or two reviews. On the other hand, some hotels who are also rated at 5 have over 300 reviews. Is there a way to give priority or more influence to hotels that have been rated more frequently?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you simply assing a higher weight to those who have more reviews in whatever model you are using?

Answer (score 0):

That is commonly called "support", the is the number of occurrences of the class in the specified dataset.

There are several ways to use support:

- Filter data - Only allow instances with a specific number of occurrences.
- Weighted loss - Many loss functions give more weight to examples that occur more often. Also, it is often possible to increase the weightings.
- Bayesian frameworks - Bayesian machine learning gives explicit uncertainty predictions, support is one of the primary drivers of uncertainty.